# Enumerate function with similar strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, enumerate

Writing a script to read several csv files. I have a list of 3 distinct barcodes. Each code has three different files. Each code has the same prefix '5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz'. This is part of a longer lists of barcodes.

I have another list of directories where the barcodes are found. In order for the script to run, I need all three files

My goal is build a dictionary of distinct barcodes and directories. I'm having a problem with the output. One of the three barcodes is missing. '5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1'. I think the issue is with the enumerate function in the for loop.

```
 directories = ['C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1_FIRST.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11_FIRST.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12_FIRST.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1_SECOND.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11_SECOND.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12_SECOND.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1_THIRD.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11_THIRD.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12_THIRD.csv']

barcodes = ['5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12']

#print(directories)
#print(barcodes)

barcodes = list(set(barcodes))
barcodes = [s for s in barcodes if "5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz" in s] #Want to process codes with this prefix 
directories = list(set(directories))
#print(directories)
directories = [s for s in directories if "5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz" in s]
#print(directories)

barcode_dirs_indexes =[]
for b_code in barcodes:
   #print(b_code)
   index = [i for i,x in enumerate(directories) if b_code in x] #I think the issue is here
   barcode_dirs_indexes.append(index)
   #print(barcode_dirs_indexes)

barcode_dirs = [[directories[x] for x in y] for y in barcode_dirs_indexes]

# only process barcode with 3 directories, i.e. the barcode has 3 files 
data_barcode_dir_indx = [i for i,x  in enumerate(barcode_dirs) if len(x) == 3 ]
data_barcode_dirs = [x for x in barcode_dirs if len(x) == 3]
#print(data_barcode_dir_indx)
#print(data_barcode_dirs)
complete_data_barcodes = [barcodes[x] for x in data_barcode_dir_indx]
print(complete_data_barcodes)
dir_file_dict = dict(zip(complete_data_barcodes, data_barcode_dirs))
```

Output of dir_file_dict: It is missing barcode: 5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1

```
{'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12': ['C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12_FIRST.csv', 
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12_THIRD.csv', 'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12_SECOND.csv'], 
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11': ['C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11_FIRST.csv', 
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11_SECOND.csv', 'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11_THIRD.csv']}
```

Comment: Where did you get the directories and barcodes from? Why cant you just call all the files in desktop that end in csv, and then extract the barcodes, and group by that same barcode?

Comment: The files are from an FTP server. The server contains many barcodes but I'm only interested in those 3 codes. Ignore the 'C:/Desktop/', that was done to show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
d = {}
for i,j in zip(barcodes, directories):
  if not d.get(i):
    d[i] = []
  d[i].append(j)

print(d)
```

Comment: Only one directory outputs per barcode.It works now after i delete the lines containing list(set(barcodes)) and list(set(directories)). How do I implement the three file criteria from your code?

Comment: @defjamvan what do you mean by three file criteria?

Comment: @onyamdu. I have a condition here to only use barcodes that have all three .csv files. data_barcode_dir_indx = [i for i,x  in enumerate(barcode_dirs) if len(x) == 3 ] data_barcode_dirs = [x for x in barcode_dirs if len(x) == 3]

Comment: You code allows barcodes that only have one csv files. I only want barcodes with all three files present.

Comment: @defjamvan just run `{key:val for key,val in d.items() if len(val)==3}`